# BeanManager getBeans method not taking into account repeatable annotations

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Since java 8, we can add multiple annotations of the same type to a member. We have developed a plugin system that, on server startup, collects all beans annotated with the @Extension annotation and registers them. I want to adapt that logic so members can be annotated with multiple Extension annotations and still be registered as plugins but javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager.getBeans is giving me some troubles. It's retrieving types annotated with one @Extension annotation, but not two or more. Am i missing something here ?

This is the extension annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Repeatable(Extensions.class)
public @interface Extension {...
```

This is the Extensions annotation

```
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Extensions {
    Extension[] value();
}
```

And this is how i retrieve the extension-annotated beans

```
Set<Bean<?>> pluginBeans = beanManager.getBeans(Plugin.class, ExtensionLiteral.INSTANCE);
```

The ExtensionLiteral is just a dummy instance needed to collect the extensions

```
public class ExtensionLiteral extends AnnotationLiteral<Extension> implements Extension {
...
public static final ExtensionLiteral INSTANCE = new ExtensionLiteral();
...
}
```

Comment: That is coming in weld3.0, if you are using weld

Comment: Ah damn. Is there any way to make this work until then ?

Comment: Don't use repeatable annotations? until it gets supported? or wrap make a wrapper annotations and handle it in the annotation literal implementations